# How to map "CHANGE FRAME" to mouse right click in Blender 2.80 in the VSE

Tags: interface, video-sequence-editor, shortcut, select, mouse

I use the VSE to do my video editing with the option "Select With Left" activated in Preferences.

Under those circumstances, in all beta versions of Blender 2.8, as well as the older 2.7 releases, pressing the right button with the mouse would drag the cursor easily for video and audio scrubbing and so on.

But now, pressing right click bring a context menu, and I can only restore the old behavior if I press Shift together with right click.

**So, in Blender 2.8, how can I map "Change Frame" to right mouse click while Select With Left is activated in Preferences?**

Answer (score 2):

The other answers appear to be for the animation preset, not for VSE.  For VSE, you need to do the following:

- In Blender preferences, select the Keymap section from the left navigation.
- Make sure you've picked `Left` for "Select with Mouse Button" under general preferences.
- Under SequencerCommon > Sequencer > Sequencer (Global), remove the option for "Sequencer Context Menu" (or set it to something other than `Right Mouse`).  You can drop down the menu and click the `Shift` button to swap it to shift+right mouse.
- Under SequencerCommon > Sequencer > Sequencer Tool: Tweak, change "Change Frame" to `Right Mouse`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Under the *File > User Preferences > Keymap* look for the *Animation* entry.

There should be a *Change Frame* entry. Change it to watever you like, in this case I'd advise something like `Tweak - Right`.

[image]

You may additionally have to change the context menu to open on `Right - Mouse - Release` event instead.

Comment: "You may additionally have to change the context menu to open on Right - Mouse - Release event instead.". Where can I tweak that option?

Comment: 3.30 does not have a Change Frame entry under the Animation section; you need to add it.  You can get the code to use from the other Change Frame entries; it is "anim.change_frame".

Answer (score 1):

The way to change frame using the mouse in the time based editors was changed before the official 2.80 release.

The official methods to change frame with the mouse -

- <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> under the header, where the frame/time is shown.
- with <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> **select**

  - <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> anywhere in the editor.
- with <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> **select**

  - <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> anywhere in the editor.