# Can I move my position in video editor in 2.8 by clicking a mouse button anywhere?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

If I recall correctly, prior 2.8, I could click anywhere to change my position. Now I have to click the bar with timnecodes at the top. Can I change my preferences to do that again? I am not sure about the proper terminology so I made this image to explain myself better (feel free to edit my question with proper terminology).[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Shift + Right Click will move the playhead to that frame.

For changing preferences: [How to map "CHANGE FRAME" to mouse right click in Blender 2.80 in the VSE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153125/how-to-map-change-frame-to-mouse-right-click-in-blender-2-80-in-the-vse)

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly, I tried various midifiers with leftcick and middle click but must have omitted the right-click:-).