# Can't scrub through animation in Blender 2.8

Tags: animation, timeline

Default behavior for LMB+drag in any timeline panel (timeline, dope sheet, action editor etc.) in Blender 2.8 is to create a selection box instead of scrubbing through animation. I have the B key to enter box select if I want to select things - I don't need this new method of selecting things.

I've managed to disable the selection box, but the scrub still doesn't work - now if I hold LMB and drag on the timeline it just does nothing. And I don't want to have to click on the frame number panel (which does what I want it to when I click and drag on that - see picture for clearer explanation).

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153125/how-to-map-change-frame-to-mouse-right-click-in-blender-2-80-in-the-vse/153148#153148

Answer (score 1):

Resolved:
Preferences > Keymap > Animation > Change Frame

Default value: shift right mouse

Change to: Left mouse

Note: No need to disable the "box selection" behavior. This overrides that. The above change is all you need to do.

[image]

Comment: 3.30 does not have a Change Frame entry under the Animation section; you need to add it.  You can get the code to use from the other Change Frame entries; it is "anim.change_frame".