# Hotkey to set playhead to Left mouse click

Tags: video-sequence-editor

In the Video Editor (`Sequencer`), left mouse anywhere used to move the playhead. Now one must click in the frame numbers (since left click now select, which I like) to achieve the same thing.

Is there a way to set `SHIFT + left click` anywhere moves/scrubs the playhead?

Some research shows `change frame` but I think that is now gone (can't find it in the hotkey list) [How to map “CHANGE FRAME” to mouse right click in Blender 2.80 in the VSE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/153148/112363).

Answer (score 1):

`Shift + Right Mouse Button`

At the top of the hotkey list is a search box, search for `change frame` and see/set the `Sequencer` value.